# Spaces and curly braces for variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, quoting

Is there a way to make `${VAR}` expand as if it were quoted in double quotes?

That's not what I wanted to see:

```
% A="some spaces in there"
% touch ${A}
% ls -1
in
some
spaces
there
```

Sure, I can use typical notation like `"$VAR"`. But that's cumbersome when using quotes within quoted text, etc. I wonder if there's a way of expanding ${...} notation that would treat `${...}` as if it were `"${...}"` while not using doublequotes themselves?

Comment: Why do you not want to use double quotes like `"$A"`?

Comment: There is one notation that works exactly like `"${...}"`, and it's `"${...}"`. There is no point in having two notations for the same thing.

Comment: Avoiding the double quotes is unlikely to be the right solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Not following [accepted best practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (and learning how the shell *really* works) is very likely to bite you. Repeatedly. With zombie virus-infected fangs. Some things which can help:

- You can use different quotes for different parts of a *single parameter* as long as the start and end quotes are next to each other:

  ```
  $ printf '%q\n' "foo 'bar' baz"'nuu "boo" zoo'
  foo\ \'bar\'\ baznuu\ \"boo\"\ zoo
  ```
- You can set `IFS` in a subshell to avoid screwing up your entire script:

  ```
  $ a="some spaces in there"
  $ (IFS= && touch ${a})
  $ ls -1
  some spaces in there
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [IFS variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)
to disregard spaces when the shell splits variables. This is also useful when taking in input that may contain spaces in loops.

```
$ cat /tmp/t.sh
IFS="$(printf '\n\t')"
A="some spaces in there"
touch ${A}
ls -l
$ /tmp/t.sh
some spaces in there
```

(If you have characters like * in your strings try a set -f to disable globbing (see help set) thanks @glenn jackman. But really, putting a * in a filename is asking for trouble!)

And the original:

```
$ cat /tmp/t.sh
#!/bin/bash
A="some spaces in there"
touch ${A}
ls -1
$ /tmp/t.sh 
in
some
spaces
there
$
```

Comment: You'll also want to `set -f` to turn off filename generation too: `A="some * in there"; touch $A` will be a problem otherwise